# removing "~/" from the first of an sqldatareader object

Tags: asp.net, database, url, sqldatareader

I am saving the url of the pictures with `FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path)` and I initialize the path variable :

```
path = "~/Persian/slideshow/pictures/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
```

I must add the '~/' because for inserting to the solution and so inserting to the database I need to do so. my problem is that when I want to read this map path from the database and create the tag of image, I can not remove the '~/' part from the object. here is my code:

```
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
imageList = "";
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    url = dataReader["PhotoUrl"].ToString();
    url = url.Substring(2, url.Length - 2);
    imageList += "{ image: '" + url + "', title: '" + dataReader["PhotoTitle"] + "', thumb: '" + dataReader["PhotoUrl"] + "', url: '" + dataReader["PhotoUrl"] + "' },";
}
```

the problem here is I can not use the string related functions for correcting the path. 
What can I do ?

Thank You so much ;)

Comment: What do you want url to look like in the JSON?

Comment: The Substring works. It looks like in the ImageList you are reusing the dataReader["PhotoUrl"] and should use the url variable. If that isn't the problem can you show what imageList contains and what you are looking for?

Comment: No Just I want to remove the ~/ from the first of url which is added using the FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path)) to the url. the problem is when I read this field from the database it is not a string.so I can not do that

Comment: <%=imagelist%> is used in the script which load the pictures in gallery page. it is a protected string and the error I get from the above code is : "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.\r\nParameter name: startIndex"

Comment: Try  dataReader["PhotoUrl"].ToString()

Comment: no it does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the above code is completely true and work. my problem was that I remove the / from the begin of url.

```
path = "~/Persian/slideshow/pictures/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            imageList = "";
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                url = dataReader["PhotoUrl"].ToString();
                url = url.Substring(1);
                imageList += "{ image: '" + url + "', title: '" + dataReader["PhotoTitle"] + "', thumb: '" + dataReader["PhotoUrl"] + "', url: '" + dataReader["PhotoUrl"] + "' },";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have path saved in DB as  "~/Persian/slideshow/pictures/aa.gif" and you want to have "/Persian/slideshow/pictures/aa.gif" in your code , you can use .ToString() and substring to acieve this.

```
  string dbpath = "~/Persian/slideshow/pictures/aa.gif" ; // actual dbpath will be DataReaderObj["path"].ToString();
  string newpath = dbpath.Substring(1, dbpath.Length - 1); // this will remove ~ only
  string newpath = dbpath.Substring(2, dbpath.Length - 2); // to remove ~/
```

Use above lines inside while loop, to get required file path.

Comment: yeah! that is the answer ;)